# Excel array formula for counting consecutive identical values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a sequence of integers and I want to compute, at each point of the sequence, how long is the current sequence of identical values. E.g., if the sequence is (0,1,1,1,0,0), I want as output (1,1,2,3,1,2).

This is easy to do with non-array formulas:

```
B2 =100                         # Length of the sequence
D2 =SEQUENCE(B2)              
E2 =RANDARRAY(B2,,0,1,TRUE)     # My sequence
F2 =IF(OR(D2=1,E2<>E1),1,F1+1)  # Formula copied down until the end of the sequence (F101)
```

Now, I'd like to have an array formula in column `F`, because I don't know in advance how long my sequence will be. My best attempt is:

```
G2 =LET(s,E2#,SCAN(0,D2#,LAMBDA(a,x,IF(OR(x=1,INDEX(s,x)<>INDEX(s,x-1)),1,a+1))))
```

[image: Screenshot]

The formula works, but it is very slow. The non-array formula `F2` above works almost instantly even for `B2` equal to 100,000, the array formula struggles already for `B2` equal to 10,000.

Any idea on making the array formula as fast as the non-array one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using XMATCH and BYROW works for me with 100,000 rows:

```
=BYROW(E2#,LAMBDA(a,LET(b,ROW(a),s,E2#,b-1-IFERROR(XMATCH(ABS(a-1),INDEX(s,1):INDEX(s,b-1),0,-1),0))))
```

It goes row by row.  It matches bottom up from the point at which it is looking for the opposite number: `ABS(a-1)`  Then it subtracts that from the current row to return the count.

This does not require column D.

I tested 100,000 and it is fairly responsive 1,000,000 takes a few seconds.

[image]

Comment: That's a good answer! Could it be made to work if there are more than two values in column `E`?

Comment: @user175348 that is a new question and deserves its own post.  That way you can give proper examples of data and expected output.

Comment: I have submitted a new question at https://superuser.com/questions/1719659/fast-array-formula-for-running-total-of-a-column-for-consecutive-dentical-values