# Fast array formula for running total of a column for consecutive identical values in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

This is a follow-up question to [Excel array formula for counting consecutive identical values](https://superuser.com/questions/1719341/excel-array-formula-for-counting-consecutive-identical-values/1719381?noredirect=1#comment2654284_1719381). Here the problem is slightly more complicated.

I have a column (column `E`) with integer values, and another column (`F`) with arbitrary values. I want to compute, in column `G`, the running total of `F`, but limited to the segment of consecutive rows where the current value of `F` is constant. The description may be easier to understand with a formula:

```
B2 =100                          # Length of sequence
B3 =3                            # Possible values in column E
D2 =SEQUENCE(B2)                 # Auxiliary variable
E2 =RANDARRAY(B2,,1,B3,TRUE)     # Sequence of integers between 1 and B3
F2 =RANDARRAY(B2)                # Sequence of values to be summed

G2 =IF(OR(D2=1,E2<>E1),0,G1)+F2  # Desired output, non-array formula version.
                                 # If the current value in E is the same 
                                 # as in the previous row, sum to the running total of F,
                                 # else start again with the current value of F.
                                 # Formula needs to be copied along the other columns.
```

As in the linked question, I don't know in advance how long the sequence will be and I would like to use an array formula to automatically adjust the length of the output, instead of repeating the formula in `G2` in the `G` column.

The following formula works:

```
H2 =LET(s,E2#,v,F2#,SCAN(0,D2#,LAMBDA(a,x,IF(OR(x=1,INDEX(s,x)<>INDEX(s,x-1)),0,a)+INDEX(v,x))))
```

but is much slower than the `G2` formula above: it becomes slow when the sequence has a length in the thousands, while the `G2` formula can easily handle hundreds of thousands of values.

How can I make the array formula as fast as the non-array formula?

(and BTW, why is the array formula so slow? All operations inside it should be very fast.)

PS
In the linked question, user Scott Craner found a [clever formula](https://superuser.com/a/1719381/175348), using `BYROW` instead of `SCAN`, but it relies on the fact that column `E` only contains two possible distinct values.

**Edit**

I finally found an array formula that is *almost* as fast (i.e. about 3 times slower) as the non-array version:

```
H2 =LET(
        sect, E2#,
        values, F2#,
        n, ROWS(sect),
        s, SEQUENCE(n),
        sentinel_val, -1,
        same_as_next, FILTER(sect, s > 1) = FILTER(sect, s < n),
        adj_values, 
            CHOOSE(
                1 + (s > 1), 
                sentinel_val, 
                INDEX(
                    CHOOSE(same_as_next + 1, sentinel_val, values), 
                    s - 1)
                ),
        prev_sum, 
            SCAN(
                0, 
                adj_values, 
                LAMBDA(a,x, IF(x < 0, 0, a + x))
            ),
        prev_sum + values
   )
```

Answer (score 1):

Building off my other formula we look for all the numbers that are not the one at that row and do a sum of F from where it starts to the current row.

```
=BYROW(E2#,LAMBDA(a,LET(b,ROW(a),s,E2#,f,F2#,m,MAX(IFERROR(XMATCH(FILTER(SEQUENCE(B3),SEQUENCE(B3)<>a),INDEX(s,1):INDEX(s,b-1),0,-1),0)+1),SUM(INDEX(f,m):INDEX(f,b-1)))))
```

Again I do not rely on D so it can be omitted if desired.

As B3 increases so does the time it takes.  But with B3 = 3 doing 100,000 is not long

[image]

Array formula are slow, we can mitigate some of that using things like XMATCH and shrinking the ranges to which we are actually doing the functions.  But they will never beat simple non array formula for large data sets.

So another option is to just use the simple formula wrapped in another IF:

```
=IF(F2<>"",IF(OR(D2=1,E2<>E1),0,G1)+F2,"")
```

And copy that down the full column.  It will appear like it is dynamic without the calculation cost.  In fact if F2 is blank, it would not do the rest of the equation but will just return the `""`.  Nothing will beat that in time and simplicity.

[image]

Comment: That's much faster than my array formula, but still much slower than the naïve non-array approach.

Comment: Yes, many times newer is not faster.  With each increase the number of calculations is multiplied with array formula.  You could always do: `IF(F2<>"",IF(OR(D2=1,E2<>E1),0,G1)+F2,"")` and copy that down the whole column.  Then it will return `""` where the dynamic arrays are not spilled.

Answer (score 0):

I may have missed something, but not sure of the necessity of iterative `LAMBDA`/`SCAN` approaches here. Can you not simply use:

`=SUMIFS(F2#,D2#,"<="&D2#,D2#,">"&MAXIFS(D2#,D2#,"<"&D2#,E2#,"<>"&E2#),E2#,E2#)`

for example?

Comment: For the non-array version the runtime scales linearly with the number of lines. The `SCAN`/`LAMBDA` combo should, in theory, have a similar behavior.
In reality @Scott's formula, your formula and my formula all appear to have a quadratic behavior.
Your formula in particular becomes much slower than the non-array formula somewhere between 10k and 20k rows (on my computer).

Comment: I'm not disputing your performance calculations. I'm offering a potentially more efficient spill formula.

Comment: Sorry, concurrent comment edits. Just to clarify: your formula is much faster than mine, but still much slower than the non-array version for large number of rows.
Your formula is clearly quadratic, so in some sense this is expected. 
The `SCAN` formula _should_ be linear, just by looking at it, but evidently it is not, and I don't understand why (hence in particular the second part of my question: 
"(and BTW, why is the array formula so slow? All operations inside it should be very fast.)"